# Compile a minimal Linux 3.5 Kernel for Hyper-V

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel, hyper-v

I'm looking for to compile a minimal linux 3.5 kernel for Hyper-V.

The "selecting" hyper-v drivers part is quite easy. However, how to remove unnecessary modules/drivers and improve performance.

Comment: Removing unnecessary modules is not that important.

Answer (score 1):

Read Linux Kernel in a Nutshell by Greg Kroah

http://www.kroah.com/lkn/